# What does "pull out" mean?

Tags: meaning

I read Henry and Mudge and the Funny Lunch.
And I found this sentence in the book:
*He said that maybe it should pull out into a Watermelon Bed.*

What does it "pull out" mean?
And I wonder why author put "Watermelon Bed" instead of watermelon bed.

Comment: Ruah, The most common use of "pull out" is to get something out of a container. For example, "She opened her backpack and pulled out a water bottle," just means that she took a water bottle out of her backpack. The use of "pull out" in your question is a special meaning for that kind of furniture. @snailplane - I, too, have never heard of a Watermelon Bed. Maybe it is outdated slang for a futon?

Comment: @snail - Most references to _watermelon bed_ are on gardening pages, but there is [this one book reference](https://www.google.com/search?q="maybe+it+should+pull+out+into+a+Watermelon+Bed"&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t). Apparently, in one of the _Henry & Mudge_ children's books, dad and son make mom a [pineapple sofa](http://www.jollytomato.com/2011/07/19/cook-your-books/), and someone gets a bit carried away, suggesting it should "pull out into a watermelon bed." A good example of why quotes should **provide context** and [identify the source](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084).

Comment: Would it be correct to think of the full phrasal verb as "pull out into"? The transformation is part of the whole verb package?

Answer (score 3):

This sentence means that the couch (or whatever they're talking about) can be turned into a bed by pulling part of it away from the rest, so that it unfolds.

For example, I could say, "that couch is a futon. It pulls out into a bed." That means that I can unfold the couch to make it a bed.

Comment: In this case, the part that pulls out would be a [slice of watermelon](http://livinglearninglaughing.blogspot.com/2010/05/my-watermelon-bed.html), pulling out from the [pineapple sofa](http://www.scholastic.com/teachers/book/henry-and-mudge-and-funny-lunch), seen on the cover of [this book](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81M86k8L3KL.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a piece of furniture that will *open up* to be a "Watermelon Bed".

This would be similar to a *sofa bed*, which is normally used as a sofa, but the part below the cushions (a bed frame) can be *pulled out* to turn it into a bed.